# Desencriptación o descifrado incompleto usando Rijndael con C#

Tags: c#, seguridad, encriptación

Estoy encriptando una comunicación entre usuarios y al desencriptar lo hace de manera parcial.

El cifrado es parte del requerimiento y debe se Rijndael compatible AES (BlockSize: 128,KeySize: 256,Padding: PKCS7).

He simplificado el desarrollo a una aplicación de consola que reproduce el error.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace RijndaelConsoleApplication
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string mensaje = "Hola Mundo! Este es un mensaje secreto";
        Console.WriteLine("Original:  " + mensaje);
        /* Emisor */
        Seguridad rijndael1 = new Seguridad();
        string cifrado = rijndael1.EncryptToString(mensaje);
        Console.WriteLine("Cifrado: " + cifrado);

        /* Receptor, instancia de seguridad separada por que es otra aplicacion la que recibe el texto encriptado */
        Seguridad rijndael2 = new Seguridad();
        string descifrado = rijndael2.DecryptToString(cifrado);
        Console.WriteLine("Descifrado: " + descifrado);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Clase que implementa el cifrado de los mensajes.
/// </summary>
public class Seguridad
{
    private const string _claveSecreta = "esUnaClaveSecretaDe32Caracteres_"; /* 32 caracteres.*/
    private ICryptoTransform EncryptorTransform, DecryptorTransform;
    private System.Text.ASCIIEncoding TextEncoder;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public Seguridad()
    {
        TextEncoder = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();

        using (RijndaelManaged raindoll = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            raindoll.BlockSize = 128; // bloques de 128 bits los hace compatible con AES.
            raindoll.KeySize = 256; // es el size por defecto.
            raindoll.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            raindoll.Key = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_claveSecreta); /* Longitud de la clave es de 32 bytes. 32*8=256 que es el keysize*/

            EncryptorTransform = raindoll.CreateEncryptor();
            DecryptorTransform = raindoll.CreateDecryptor();
        }
    }

    public string EncryptToString(string texto)
    {
        return Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypt(texto));
    }

    public string DecryptToString(string textoCifrado)
    {
        return Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(textoCifrado));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Encriptador
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="texto">Texto a cifrar</param>
    /// <returns>cadena de bytes</returns>
    private byte[] Encrypt(string texto)
    {
        Byte[] encrypted = null;
        Byte[] bytesText = TextEncoder.GetBytes(texto);

        using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream encryptStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, this.EncryptorTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                encryptStream.Write(bytesText, 0, bytesText.Length);
                encryptStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            }
            encrypted = memStream.ToArray();
        }

        return encrypted;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Desencriptador
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="encryptado">cadena de bytes cifrados</param>
    /// <returns>texto descifrado.</returns>
    private string Decrypt(byte[] encryptado)
    {
        Byte[] decryptedBytes = null;

        using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream decryptStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, this.DecryptorTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                decryptStream.Write(encryptado, 0, encryptado.Length);
            }

            decryptedBytes = memStream.ToArray();
        }

        return this.TextEncoder.GetString(decryptedBytes);
    }
}
}
```

Aquí dejo una captura del error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luego de varios meses encontré la respuesta.
Resulta que el estandard Rijndael cuando se genera un vector inicial aleatorio, lo agrega dentro del cifrado del texto.

Por lo que omitiendo los 16 bytes se evita estos caracteres extraños que agregaba. (En mi caso no necesito obtener el IV del texto cifrado).
Aquí esta el código:

```
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;
    using System.Text;

    namespace RijndaelConsoleApplication
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string mensaje = "Hola Mundo! Este es un mensaje secreto";
                Console.WriteLine("Original:  " + mensaje);
                /* Emisor */
                Seguridad rijndael1 = new Seguridad();
                string cifrado = rijndael1.EncryptToString(mensaje);
                Console.WriteLine("Cifrado: " + cifrado);

                /* Receptor, instancia de seguridad separada por que es otra aplicacion la que recibe el texto encriptado */
                Seguridad rijndael2 = new Seguridad();
                string descifrado = rijndael2.DecryptToString(cifrado);
                Console.WriteLine("Descifrado: " + descifrado);

                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clase que implementa el cifrado de los mensajes.
        /// </summary>
        public class Seguridad
        {
            private const string _claveSecreta = "esUnaClaveSecretaDe32Caracteres_"; /* Longitud de la clave es de 32 bytes. 32*8=256 que es el keysize*/
            private ICryptoTransform EncryptorTransform, DecryptorTransform;
            private System.Text.ASCIIEncoding TextEncoder;

            /// <summary>
            /// Constructor
            /// </summary>
            public Seguridad()
            {
                TextEncoder = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();

                using (RijndaelManaged raindoll = new RijndaelManaged())
                {
                    raindoll.BlockSize = 128; // bloques de 128 bits los hace compatible con AES.
                    raindoll.KeySize = 256; // es el size por defecto.
                    raindoll.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                    raindoll.Key = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_claveSecreta); /* Longitud de la clave es de 32 bytes. 32*8=256 que es el keysize*/
                    raindoll.GenerateIV(); /* La longitud del vector es la mitad de la del bloque es decir: 16 bytes */

                    EncryptorTransform = raindoll.CreateEncryptor();
                    DecryptorTransform = raindoll.CreateDecryptor();
                }
            }

            public string EncryptToString(string texto)
            {
                return Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypt(texto));
            }

            public string DecryptToString(string textoCifrado)
            {
                return Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(textoCifrado));
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Encriptador
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="texto">Texto a cifrar</param>
            /// <returns>cadena de bytes</returns>
            private byte[] Encrypt(string texto)
            {
                Byte[] encrypted = null;
                Byte[] bytesText = TextEncoder.GetBytes(texto);

                using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream encryptStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, this.EncryptorTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        /* Agrego 16 bytes. La longitud del vector de inicializacion */
                        encryptStream.Write(new Byte[16], 0, 16);
                        encryptStream.Write(bytesText, 0, bytesText.Length);
                        encryptStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                    }
                    encrypted = memStream.ToArray();
                }

                return encrypted;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Desencriptador
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="encryptado">cadena de bytes cifrados</param>
            /// <returns>texto descifrado.</returns>
            private string Decrypt(byte[] encryptado)
            {
                Byte[] decryptedBytes = null;

                using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream decryptStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, this.DecryptorTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        decryptStream.Write(encryptado, 0, encryptado.Length);
                    }

                    decryptedBytes = memStream.ToArray();
                }

                /* Remuevo 16 bytes. La longitud del vector de inicializacion */
                return this.TextEncoder.GetString(decryptedBytes.Skip(16).Take(decryptedBytes.Length).ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
```

Un ejemplo de ejecución:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Buen día, primero que todo [aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged(v=vs.110).aspx) te dejo el link que MSDN pone a disposición con la información sobre la clase `RijndaelManaged`, que usas para tu código. Ahora bien, la diferencia del ejemplo que nos deja Microsoft al código tuyo es que ellos solo crean un una instancia de la clase `RijndaelManaged`, por tanto los valores son los mismos en la instancia.

Ahora bien, para encriptar o desencriptar, esta clase utiliza principalmente dos propiedades de la clase que son [Key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.key(v=vs.110).aspx) y [IV](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.iv(v=vs.110).aspx), las dos al crear una instancia nueva del objeto adquieren un valor Random por defecto. Tu estás asignando el `Key`, pero nunca estás cambiando el `IV`.

Lo que te recomiendo y para seguir con el modelo que tienes, declarar un string _IVSecreta y asignarlo a la propiedad IV.

```
//Esto iría dentro del objeto Seguridad.    
private const string _IVScreta = "1234567890abcdef"; /*16 caracteres, pues debe ser la mitad de la clave*/
```

Después más abajo lo asignas.

```
using (RijndaelManaged raindoll = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                raindoll.BlockSize = 128; // bloques de 128 bits los hace compatible con AES.
                raindoll.KeySize = 256; // es el size por defecto.
                raindoll.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                raindoll.Key = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_claveSecreta); /* Longitud de la clave es de 32 bytes. 32*8=256 que es el keysize*/
                raindoll.IV = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_IVScreta); //aquí asignas lo antes declarado arriba
                EncryptorTransform = raindoll.CreateEncryptor();
                DecryptorTransform = raindoll.CreateDecryptor();

            }
```

[Aquí](http://ideone.com/I5uBhf) te dejo el código ya compilado y sirviendo.

Posdata.

Los métodos `CreateEncryptor` y `CreateDecryptor`, así como lo usas pasan los valores `Key` y `IV` del objeto `RijndaelManaged`, que los está llamando, por eso es que pasaban un valor diferente de la propiedad `IV`, pero estos métodos también están sobrecargados, para poderles pasar estos dos valores por parámetro. Aquí te dejo la información de la sobrecarga de [CreateEncryptor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9df14hc(v=vs.110).aspx) y [CreateDecryptor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2f5ff61x(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Según tengo entendido el vector inicial debería ser aleatorio y no fijo. Por ejemplo usando:
  raindoll.GenerateIV();
Que tampoco me funciona. Igual agradezco tu solución.

Comment: Lo que se debería es guardar estos dos valores, en un lugar separado y seguro, y a la hora de crear una instancia, traerlos y pasarlos como parámetros a la hora de llamar los métodos CreateEncryptor o CreateDecryptor, por eso es que estos métodos pueden recibir como parámetros los valores de Key y IV, si no se ocupara del IV, entonces el método solo pediría el Key

Answer (score 0):

Cambia tú línea de código:

```
raindoll.Key = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_claveSecreta);
```

Por las siguientes líneas de código:

```
//raindoll.Key = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_claveSecreta); /* Longitud de la clave es de 32 bytes. 32*8=256 que es el keysize*/

Rfc2898DeriveBytes pwdGen = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(_claveSecreta, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("12345678"));
byte[] key = pwdGen.GetBytes(raindoll.KeySize / 8);   //This will generate a 256 bits key
byte[] iv = pwdGen.GetBytes(raindoll.BlockSize / 8);

raindoll.Key = key;
raindoll.IV = iv;
```

Comment: El problema con esta solución es que estás fijando el vector inicial.

Es lo mismo que hacer:
raindoll.IV = new byte[raindoll.IV.Length];

Lo recomendable es que sea aleatorio.

Comment: Perfecta esta aclaración